# loop through two lists at the same time and passing each item to method

Tags: c#, .net, list, c#-4.0, foreach

I have got two list of strings like this

```
list<string> OldlicenseList = new List<string>{"abcs", "rtets", "taya", "tctct"}; //sample data

list<string> subscriptionList = new List<string> {"udud", "ydyyd" , "tsts","tstst", "hghs"} //Sample data
```

so I am doing like this below

```
  foreach (var strOldLicense in OldlicenseList)
  {
         foreach (var subscriptionList in objSubscription.lstClsLicense)
         {
               newLicenseList.Add(subscriptionList.license_key);
               isInserted = _objcertificate.UpdateClpInternalLicense(subscriptionKey, _objUserInfo.GetUserAcctId(), strOldLicense, subscriptionList.license_key, expiryDT);

               if (!isInserted)
               {
                   new Log().logInfo(method, "Unable to update the Subscription key." + certID);
                   lblErrWithRenewSubKey.Text = "Application could not process your request. The error has been logged.";
                   lblErrWithRenewSubKey.Visible = true;
                   return;
               }
               insertCount++;

               if (insertCount >= 4)
               {
                        break;
               }
         }

    }
```

here i need pass each item form both the lists to the method **UpdateClpInternalLicense** and second list (**subscriptionList** ) is having 5 items but i need to stop sending 5 th item to that method..

I tried above mentioned way, but the problem is once inner loop is completed .. it will loop through again since there are 4 items in first list ..

I need to pass one item from each list to that method until 4 iterations, after 4th iteration i need to come out from both loops ..

Would any one please suggest any ideas, that would be very grateful ..

Many thanks in advance..

Comment: Mmm... just add another `if (insertCount >= 4) { break; }` in your first foreach...?

Comment: did you try using ```for``` instead of ```foreach``` ?

Comment: Why not use simple 'for' loop instead of 'foreach' and run to as many iteration you want

Comment: i am able to pass only one item from outer list(1st list) ..but that's not what i want ... once i passed one item from outer list it will enter into second loop and second loop will take same item from first list till it finishes the count..

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var query =
    from strOldLicense in OldlicenseList
    from subscriptionList in objSubscription.lstClsLicense
    select new { strOldLicense, subscriptionList };

foreach (var x in query)
{
    newLicenseList.Add(x.subscriptionList.license_key);
    isInserted = _objcertificate.UpdateClpInternalLicense(subscriptionKey, _objUserInfo.GetUserAcctId(), x.strOldLicense, x.subscriptionList.license_key, expiryDT);

    if (!isInserted)
    {
        new Log().logInfo(method, "Unable to update the Subscription key." + certID);
        lblErrWithRenewSubKey.Text = "Application could not process your request. The error has been logged.";
        lblErrWithRenewSubKey.Visible = true;
        return;
    }
    insertCount++;

    if (insertCount >= 4)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

This gets it down to a single list that you're iterating through so then the `break` will work.

Comment: we have a problem with this  "x.strOldLicense"  every time this variable is holding only first license when we loop through the query .. Could you please help on this..

Comment: @EnigmaState - Try running through the entire `query` enumerable. It should be fine. I'm guessing that `insertCount` exceeds `4` before you get the next `x.strOldLicense` value.

Comment: no in this statement   isInserted = _objcertificate.UpdateClpInternalLicense(subscriptionKey, _objUserInfo.GetUserAcctId(), x.strOldLicense, x.subscriptionList.license_key, expiryDT);  this varaible "x.strOldLicense" holding always first license only when we loop through the query results\

Comment: @EnigmaState - Yes, but that's not what I asked you to do. Run through the entire `query` enumerable and check that - don't run the code inside the `foreach` - put in a `Console.WriteLine(...)` instead so that you can absolutely check every value of `x`. If they are all the same then `OldlicenseList` must only have a single value.

Comment: @EnigmaState - How did you go?

Comment: Oldlicenselist is having 4 different licenses ... where as "x.subscriptionList" is a array list it is having 5 sets of ( some other parameters with license key )...

Comment: @EnigmaState - I don't know what you mean by that. I tested my code with your sample data and it worked fine (after I fixed the syntax errors).

Comment: please give me a sec i will upload the Query results ...where it will be the syntax error .. would you please let me know..

Comment: @EnigmaState - In your sample data you define a list called `subscriptionList`, but in your code you have `foreach (var subscriptionList in objSubscription.lstClsLicense)`. Other than that your sample code has `list<string>`, not `List<string>`, and the second line of the sample doesn't end with a `;`.